# add object into GSON array android studio

Tags: android, gson

hey guys im using android's gson library to parse my JSON. everything is working fine in that I have that selected goal array sometimes it is full of values and sometimes it is an empty array. when array is empty I want to push an object init when I try to add its index

```
selected_goal.add(INDEX,VALUE)
```

I want to push an object at the place of value please help me how can I do it…

this is my pojo:

```
 public class SelectedGoal {

        @SerializedName("id")
        @Expose
        private String id;
        @SerializedName("goal_name")
        @Expose
        private String goalName;
        @SerializedName("image")
        @Expose
        private String image;
        @SerializedName("position")
        @Expose
        private String position;
        @SerializedName("athlete_id")
        @Expose
        private String athleteId;
        @SerializedName("coach_id")
        @Expose
        private String coachId;
        @SerializedName("current_goal_id")
        @Expose
        private String currentGoalId;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getGoalName() {
            return goalName;
        }

        public void setGoalName(String goalName) {
            this.goalName = goalName;
        }

        public String getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public void setImage(String image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        public String getPosition() {
            return position;
        }

        public void setPosition(String position) {
            this.position = position;
        }

        public String getAthleteId() {
            return athleteId;
        }

        public void setAthleteId(String athleteId) {
            this.athleteId = athleteId;
        }

        public String getCoachId() {
            return coachId;
        }

        public void setCoachId(String coachId) {
            this.coachId = coachId;
        }

        public String getCurrentGoalId() {
            return currentGoalId;
        }

        public void setCurrentGoalId(String currentGoalId) {
            this.currentGoalId = currentGoalId;
        }

    }
```

Comment: what's the problem doing that ?

Comment: @VivekMishra how can I add object into this.

Comment: create an object of your pojo class and it it to your array

Comment: List< SelectedGoal> selected_goal; im using it like this but like selected.get(0).getGoalname();  but im confused how can I add into it.

Comment: list has add() method to add objects at given position too. Use that.

Comment: selected_goal.add(0,OBJECT); I know this is the function which is used to put object but i m confuse that how can make that object is it json object type or what ..

Comment: class type object

Comment: did you any snippet or example @VivekMishra coz im still cant get that

Comment: create an object of your selected goal class and add that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
selected_goal.add(INDEX,new SelectedGoal());
```

**EDIT-** To set values, make constuctor in your SelectedGoal class like.

```
public SelectedGoal(String id, String goalName, String image, String 
position, String athleteId, String coachId, String currentGoalId) {
    this.id = id;
    this.goalName = goalName;
    this.image = image;
    this.position = position;
    this.athleteId = athleteId;
    this.coachId = coachId;
    this.currentGoalId = currentGoalId;
}
```

finally add your object into list like..

```
 selected_goal.add(INDEX,new SelectedGoal(id,goalName,image,position,athleteId,coachId,currentGoalId));
```

Comment: thanks for positive response. but I want to add object with values like selectedGoal("GoalName",goalId) etc.. do I need to make a constructer of that class with setter getter function?

Comment: @Tanveerbyn yes you need to make constructor in your pojo class and Pass values to class.

Comment: @Tanveerbyn see my edits. I wish..it will be helpful for you :)

Comment: not working getting this error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: @Tanveerbyn its working fine here..but without any annotation.

Comment: selected_goal = new ArrayList<SelectedGoal>(); by adding this line its working thanks

Comment: now how can I add into nested pojo like AthleteData.get(position).getSelectedAthleteGoal().add(0,new SelectedAthleteGoal(goalArray.get(i).getId(),goalArray.get(i).getGoalName(),goalArray.get(i).getImage(),goalArray.get(i).getPosition(),AthleteID,CoachID,goalArray.get(i).getId()));

Comment: this is based on its position and this is nested

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195570/discussion-between-tanveerbyn-and-prachi-singh).

Comment: @Tanveerbyn if you have other queries you should add new question to stackoverflow to get better guidence..happy codding :)